# How do I use the word 'opposition' in political contexts?

Tags: grammar, articles

If I talk about opposition in general, not with respect to any particular country, am I supposed to drop the article altogether or swap it for an indefinite one? Suppose

> If a ruler forcefully excludes opposition from participating in domestic politics, bottled-up frustration of disadvantaged citizens may be exploited by radical underground groups.

Comment: Your sentence sounds reasonable to me.  There's something very slightly iffy about the lack of the definite article to my ear, but the way you put it is less ambiguous than "the opposition", which does sound like you might be talking about say one political party (but in the wider context of a paragraph that might be clear).  Probably there are different sentence constructions or vocab that work even better but I can't think of them!

Comment: I think *the* is still acceptable - it's still a specific *opposition* to the ruler in question. Your sentence works fine, too. *An opposition* would sound odd - it makes it seem like the ruler has multiple *oppositions* and chooses to exclude one, which doesn't match the usual use of *the opposition* to collectively refer to everyone opposing a ruler.

Comment: It sounds better (to me) if you add *parties*: "If a ruler forcefully excludes opposition parties from participating in domestic politics..." If the opposition are trying to *participate* surely they have a party or parties, whose *representatives* are then excluded. Or, if opposition *parties* are banned, perhaps you should say, "If a ruler forcefully excludes opposition **movements** from participating in domestic politics..."